# powershell throws PipelineStoppedException for an async call

Tags: powershell

Below code throws PipelineStoppedException when it tries to end invoke. Could anybody see anything wrong? Thanks.

```
        using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
        {                
                powershell.AddScript(script);
                powershell.Runspace = CreateRunspace();
                lock (powershell.Runspace)
                {
                    powershell.BeginInvoke(
                                input,
                                setting,
                                delegate(IAsyncResult result)
                                {                                       
                                  powershell.EndInvoke(result); // throw pipeline stopped exception.                                         
                                },
                               null);
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BeginInvoke returns immediately - by design - so the using clause closes, disposing the powershell instance before EndInvoke gets called. Use regular synchronous Invoke. You are mixing up sync and async patterns.

Comment: Ok, so please mark my response as the answer if you are satisfied. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to use BeginInvoke() and EndInvoke() in a real async way. That's, I just call BeginInvoke() and then forget instead of using EndInvoke to wait for the return or result. I like EndInvoke to be a callback function called automatically when BeginInvoke() finishes. How can I do this?

Comment: You need to ensure the powershell object outlives the endinvoke call - your pattern is fine, you just can't dispose the engine immediately after you call BeginInvoke. Without seeing the larger design of your project I can't tell you where and how to do this.

Comment: I guess I need a new thread to create pipeline, call begininvoke, wait for endinvoke to be called, end pipeline and terminate the thread.